# Add a close/ok button to the bottom of a bootstrap multselect element?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using the Bootstrap multiselect object to filter query results on a page, and after choosing one or more options, I want a "close" or "OK" button to click on at the bottom of the selection list that will close the dropdown and fire an event.  It would be best to be at the bottom of the list and always visible, even if the list of items were long and it scrolled.

BTW, I've tried a few different ways of doing this, including appending an LI element at then end of the list, but nothing I've tried does the trick.

```
<select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
<option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
<option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
<option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
<option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
<option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
<option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
<option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
<option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
</select>

$('#multiselect').multiselect({
    maxHeight: 160,
    buttonClass: 'thisBtn',
    onDropdownShow: function(event) {
    //nothing
    }
});
```

Here's a starter Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kybqvjbp/3/

[image: bootstrap multiselect with optional Close button]

Comment: any updated code on the above close button?

Answer (score 1):

After a ton of trial and error, I've come to the conclusion that Bootstrap Multiselect isn't the right tool for the job.  I'm switching over to Sumo Select.  Here's my Fiddle to demonstrate exactly what I need: https://fiddle.jshell.net/94hwnpgx/1/